# JavaFX Window not Responding during internal elaboration

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am using javaFX with FXML file.

clicking on button the system call a function into FxmlController.java that needs some second to elaborate the result.

During the elaboration the GUI seems freezed until the result has been obtained.
I know that for GUI I should use the threding but i don't know how.
However this is a piece of code of my FXMLController.java that is invocated onClick button:

```
 private void printOut() {
    List<String> listString = null;
    Hyperlink hyperLink = new Hyperlink("test");
    VBox vBox = Main.getVbox();
    vBox.getChildren().clear();
    listString = readAllDoc();  //this is the function that needs time to run
    vBox.getChildren().add(hyperLink);
    }
```

Furthermore the function printOut is called in the fxml file...see below:

```
<Button fx:id="read" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="401.0"
        mnemonicParsing="false" text="Read All" onAction="#printOut" />
```

The main is this:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException
{   


    // Create the FXMLLoader 
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    // Path to the FXML File
    String fxmlDocPath = getClass().getResource("MyFXML.fxml").getPath();

    FileInputStream fxmlStream = new FileInputStream(fxmlDocPath);

    // Create the Pane and all Details
    AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load(fxmlStream);
    setPrimaryRoot(root);

    ScrollPane sp = (ScrollPane) root.getChildren().get(2);
    VBox vb = (VBox) sp.getContent();
    setScrollPane(sp);
    setVbox(vb);

    // Create the Scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    // Set the Scene to the Stage
    stage.setScene(scene);
    // Set the Title to the Stage
    stage.setTitle("Project");
    setPrimaryStage(stage);

    // Display the Stage
    stage.show();
}
```

how is it possible to run the function "readAllDoc" in background without freeze the GUI? thanks

Comment: sure, search for multithreading in the javafx tag ;) In fx you would start a Thread configured with a custom Task that does its work and reports back to the fx application thread when ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

i have written a new class extenderTask:

```
public class extenderTask extends Task {

private List<String> listString;

@Override
protected List<String> call() throws Exception {
    this.list = functThatTakeLotOfTime();
    return this.listString;
  }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
extenderTask task = new extenderTask();         
new Thread(task).start();
task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
setListYourVariable((List<String>) task.getValue()); ...
...(all other action)...
}
```

it was easy!! :-)